# Caching inner query in SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

How can I optimize below SQL (simplified view of my complex query.) Ideally, I should be able to cache the first SQL result (order ids) and do some kind of projection on OrderLine table in the second query.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Restrictions - I cannot create temporary tables, cursors or procedures / functions. I am connecting to Oracle 10g.

```
SELECT 'Object_id', id, mod_id FROM
(
    (Select 'Order_id', order_id, mod_id FROM Orders)
    UNION
    (select 'Order_line_id', order_line_id, mod_id FROM OrderLine 
        WHERE order_id IN (Select order_id FROM Orders)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer is responsible for optimizing your query; relax and let it do its stuff.

Any explicit caching you attempt will involve things like temporary tables (which you've ruled out), so you can only make the common query more explicit, perhaps, by using a CTE (common table expression, aka WITH clause) to name the common sub-query.  But the optimizer might well process things the same way regardless.

You can replace the IN clause with a JOIN; that will likely be faster.  Again, the optimizer might do that anyway.  However, that's not a caching operation; it is a standard query rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

You can design your queries based on following example:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    Select 'Order_id' Descr, order_id, mod_id FROM Orders
)
, CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Order_line_id' Descr, order_line_id, mod_id FROM OrderLine ol
    WHERE EXISTS (Select order_id FROM CTE WHERE order_id = ol.order_id)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2;
```

Comment: Got to it before I could submit!

Comment: @karephul The idea with a CTE is that it can find the result set and use those in a query afterwards. It has the drawback of allowing infinite recursion and turing completeness in SQL.

Comment: @DavidManheim It only allows recursion up to 100 levels, and  this will most definitely not speed up the query.  `CTE`s don't add any performance benefit at all.   I'm about 99% positive this will have the same exec plan as the original.

Comment: @JNK I agree that oracle only allows 100 levels - but otehr flavors differ. And whether or not CTEs add a performance benefit here, they can in other cases. Of course the relational algebra is reducible to the same set, so the same query plan can be generated, but that is true when refactoring any query that is properly written already.

Answer (score 0):

Select order_id, mod_id 
from orders o
inner join orderline ol 
on o.order_id = ol.order_line_id

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to remove this line:

```
 WHERE order_id IN (Select order_id FROM Orders)
```

If your database has integrity, there are no orphans allowed and this line doesn't filter anything.

Comment: And if the optimizer is clever (is the Oracle one clever enough?) it will optimize the query by removing this check when there is a FK in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
with myOrders as (
  select order_id,
         mod_id
  from   Orders
)
select 'order_id' obj_type,
       order_id,
       mod_id
from   myOrders

union all

select 'order_line_id' obj_type,
       order_line_id,
       mod_id
from   OrderLine
join   myOrders
on     OrderLine.order_id = myOrders.order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'Object_id', id, mod_id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN CROSSNUM = 1 THEN 'Order_ID'
            ELSE 'Order_Line_ID'
        END AS Object_ID,
        CASE
            WHEN CROSSNUM = 1 THEN order_id
            ELSE order_line_id
        END AS id,
        CASE
            WHEN CROSSNUM = 1 THEN Orders.mod_id
            ELSE OrderLine.mod_id
        END AS mod_id
    FROM
        (Select 'Order_id', order_id, mod_id FROM Orders) Orders
    LEFT JOIN (select 'Order_line_id', order_line_id, mod_id FROM OrderLine) OrderLine
        ON Orders.Order_id = OrderLine.Order_Id
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 AS CROSSNUM FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS CROSSNUM FROM DUAL
    ) X
WHERE
    NOT (CROSSNUM = 2 AND order_line_id IS NULL)
)
```